# Cambiar el grosor a borde redondo en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de una calculadora (lo típico que te mandan hacer cuando empiezas). Tengo una duda que creo que no es posible realizar: quiero crear un borde redondo para los botones de la calculadora pero no puedo modificar el grosor, el borde lo modifico con la interface Border pero por lo que veo ninguno de sus métodos sirve para cambiar este valor.

Os dejo parte del código:

```
//-----------clase con la interface para modificar el borde para que sea redondo

class RoundedBorder implements Border {

    private int radius;

    RoundedBorder(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(this.radius + 1, this.radius + 1, this.radius + 2, this.radius);
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return false;
    }

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, radius, radius);
        //g.fillRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, 80, 80);
        
    }
}
```

```
//-----------codigo para los botones-------------

public void asignarPropiedadesComandos(JButton boton) {

    boton.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 30));
    boton.setFocusPainted(false);
    boton.setFocusable(false);
    boton.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
    boton.setBackground(new Color(65,157,255));
    boton.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta manera la aprendí gracias a [matisse](/questions/tagged/matisse), así que te diré las instrucciones para [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans).

1. Usando la vista de diseño agregas un boton a tu JFrame, JPanel o lo que sea prácticamente.
2. En la ventana de propiedades buscas *border* y das click en los tres puntos.
3. Selecciona *line border* y configura los parámetros

[image: Seleccionando LineBorder mediante matisse]

Se verá así

[image: apariencia con borde 3]

Y el código generado será:

```
jButton1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
```

Como verás el primer parámetro es el color y el segundo es el grosor.

Comment: Es una buena idea pero esa ya la tenía probada el caso es hacerlo con la clase que tengo y con la interface border, muchas gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta la interfaz `Border` que has proporcionado se puede aprovechar a la clase `Graphics2D` para manipular el grosor del borde.

He agregado un poco mas de funcionalidad al método `paintBorder`:

```
@Override
public void paintBorder(Component c,Graphics g,int x,int y,int width,int height) {
  Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
  g2.setColor(favColor);
  
  //Esto modifica el grosor
  g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));

  //Esto mejora (alisa) es aspecto de renderizado del borde
  g2.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(
                       RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                       RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
  
  g2.drawRoundRect(x+1,y+1,width-3,height-3,radius,radius);
}
```

Nos muestra un par de botones con la siguiente apariencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que es una buena aproximación a lo que buscas.
Dejo código completo de la demostración:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Demo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  private JPanel contentPane;
  private JButton btnMetal;
  private JButton btnNimbus;
  private JButton btnAqua;

  public Demo() {
    super("Rounded Border Demo - [JButton]");
    setSize(350,100);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    contentPane=new JPanel();
    add(contentPane);

    btnMetal=createButton("Metal LAF");
    btnMetal.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    btnMetal.addActionListener(e->System.exit(0));
    contentPane.add(btnMetal);

    btnNimbus=createButton("Nimbus LAF");
    btnNimbus.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    btnNimbus.addActionListener(e->System.exit(0));
    contentPane.add(btnNimbus);

    btnAqua=createButton("Aqua LAF");
    btnAqua.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
    btnAqua.addActionListener(e->System.exit(0));
    contentPane.add(btnAqua);

    setVisible(true);
  }

  private JButton createButton(String str) {
    JButton btn=null;
    try {
      if(str.contains("Metal"))
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
      else if(str.contains("Nimbus"))
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
      else
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel");
      btn=new JButton(str);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return btn;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          new Demo();
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

class RoundedBorder implements Border {
  private int radius;
  private Color favColor=Color.decode("#0099DD");
  //private Color favColor=Color.decode("#F55C52");

  public RoundedBorder(int radius) {
    this.radius=radius;
  }

  @Override
  public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
    return new Insets(this.radius,this.radius,this.radius,this.radius);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void paintBorder(Component c,Graphics g,int x,int y,int width,int height) {
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setColor(favColor);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
    g2.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
    g2.drawRoundRect(x+1,y+1,width-3,height-3,radius,radius);
  }
}
```

Comment: Lo voy a poner en práctica pero eso es lo que necesitaba, le di vueltas a lo del componente pero mirando y mirando la api de java no veía nada para poder modificarlo, lo voy a poner en práctica y te cuento, muchas gracias

Comment: Ha ido genial!!! al final tantas horas pensando y era hacer un casting del objeto graphics a graphics 2D para crear el trazo, muchas gracias!!!!